# How can i delete the files and folder both at the same time older than 30 days in unix

Tags: shell, unix

How can i delete the files and folder both at the same time older than 30 days in unix.
But need to make sure that folder containing files earlier than 30 days must be refrain from deletion.

How can i delete the files and folder both at the same time older than 30 days in unix.
But need to make sure that folder containing files earlier than 30 days must be refrain from deletion.

Answer (score 0):

To delete files older than 30 days you can use:

```
rm -f $(find . -mtime +30)
```

After that, you can search and show directories that not contains file after delete:

```
find . -type d | while read line; do if [ $(ls $line| wc -l) = 0 ];then echo $line; fi; done; > logerr.txt
```

Then you drop these:

```
rm -r $(find . -type d | while read line; do if [ $(ls $line| wc -l) = 0 ];then echo $line; fi; done; > logerr.txt)
```

Let me know if it was helpful.

Thank you